# Browser DOS game. How to download saved game? Cache or session storage?

Tags: google-chrome, caching, download, dos, session-storage

I'm in an interesting predicament. I'm playing this great DOS game, that I found emulated through a browser here:https://www.playdosgames.com/play/aethra-chronicles/

Now it's a long game, and I've put many days into it at this point. **This is where the puzzle comes in, and it's an interesting one.**

How do you think I could download my saved game progress?

TBH I'm not sure if it's cached, or somehow in session storage... but I have discovered that my saved games are only available from that specific tab. If I go to the site on another tab, the load games slate is empty.

BUT... here's where it's interesting. I can navigate out of the game on that tab, then load it again... and my games are still there.

Any thoughts on where it's storing these, and how I could possibly retrieve these?

[[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m3D7f.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ffbvo.png)

I've taken a look at the Google cache files, but those aren't broken out specifically.